# Why did Thor choose Earth after forging Stormbreaker?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, why didn't Thor choose to go to Titan right after the forging of Stormbreaker?

**What prompted him to go to Earth instead?**

Comment: How is this a duplicate? Hahaha, I'm asking WHY not titan, now how did he know.. ugh did you guys even read the question? I edited it to make it simpler for you guys.

Comment: I would need to rewatch the film to see the sequence of events and know that given what we saw Thanos was already on Earth when Stormbreaker was forged (maybe that is in the answer from the linked question), but what makes you think he didn't go to Titan first? Maybe he did and the editors cut that sequence out given time constraints!

Comment: This is answerable, based on the film's new junior novelisation, and not a dupe of the other question which more deals with his targeting of a specific location on Earth.

Comment: @Odin1806  If Thor went to Titan first, he's have brought the people there back with him.

Comment: I'd put forth the question: "Does Thor have any clue where Titan is?" He's been around, but nothing suggests a long-dead planet is known to him.  I suggest that Thor played the odds, hoping the Avengers (and other allies) would give the "Children of Thanos" stiff enough opposition that he could get to Earth in time.  With his help, the Children would be curb-stomped and then it would be down to waiting for Thanos to fetch the Stones himself.

Answer (score 6):

Thor had no idea that Thanos was going to rendezvous with his flunky on Titan. He did know that Thanos was first going to Knowhere to get the Reality Stone from the Collector (a relatively easy task by all accounts) then heading to Earth to get the other two extant stones. This seems, to Thor, to be the most likely place to intercept him.

> Thor's voice was detached and elsewhere. He still needed time to
> grieve and process his loss. Now was not that time. He soldiered on.
> **"The Time and Mind Stones are safe on Earth. They're with the
> Avengers."**
>
> ...
>
> Thor contmued, "As for the Soul Stone, well, no one's ever seen that. No one even knows where it is." As Thor continued, Gamora turned her gaze to the ground at her feet. The mention of the Soul Stone seemed to make her very nervous. **"Therefore, Thanos can't get it. Therefore, he's going to Knowhere."**
>
> <sub><sup>[Infinity War: Destiny Arrives](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War_-_Destiny_Arrives)</sup></sub>

Stormbreaker's Bifrost capabilities offer the unique opportunity to get to Earth before Thanos does, cutting him off at the proverbial pass.

> Giving Rocket a withering glare, Eitri explained. "It's a mold. A king's weapon. Meant to be the greatest in Asgard. In theory, it could even summon the Bifrost."
>
> At the mention of this weapon, and the possibility of wielding the Bifrost, Thor turned quickly. **If they could use this weapon to cross the Nine Realms, he could race Thanos to Earth and stop him.**

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer misses a salient point:  a bound and gagged Thor heard Thanos instruct his "Children" to go to Earth, fetch the Stones and meet him on Titan.  And then he killed Loki, and then he detonated the Asgardian ship and then he took his people thru a portal.

Comment: @Blaze Same idea though, head to Earth to stop the rest of the Black Order from getting the Mind and Time Stones.